# Winform DatagridView Numeric Column Sorting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using just a simple DataGridView to hold a bunch of data (Funny that).

I have decimals in a particular column. But when it comes to ordering by that decimal column, it orders it incorrectly. For example :

Starting order might be :

- 0.56
- 3.45
- 500.89
- 20078.90
- 1.56
- 100.29
- 2.39

The ending order would be :

- 0.56
- 100.29
- 1.56
- 20078.90
- 2.39
- 3.45
- 500.89

As you can see, it orders it starting from the first number. And then orders it in this way.

I thought possibly I could set the column to a different "ColumnType" and that may automatically do it. But there is no "Numeric" or "Decimal" column types.

I was on MSDN looking up the issue, and I could find the "sort" method that I can use on the DataGridView. But the explanation was a bit over my head, and the examples didn't use numbers, only text so I couldnt see how I was supposed to switch things up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a handler for the SortCompare event on the DataGridView with the following code:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Index == 0)
    {
        if (double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) > double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()))
        {
            e.SortResult = 1;
        }
        else if (double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) < double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()))
        {
            e.SortResult = -1;
        }             
        else
        {
            e.SortResult = 0;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

From MSDN there is this description of the SortResult values:

> Less than zero if the first cell will
>   be sorted before the second cell; zero
>   if the first cell and second cell have
>   equivalent values; greater than zero
>   if the second cell will be sorted
>   before the first cell.

Note that in my test bed the only numeric column was the first (with index 0) so that is why I have the check on the column index.

Also, depending on your needs and data you may want to refine my code - for example, my code will throw an exception if for some reason you have non numeric data in your column.

You have probably seen it, but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx) is a link to the MSDN page on customising the DataGridView sorting. As you say, they only deal with text.

Comment: Been struggling with this, your code works while the others I found didn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.  I tried using the event handler as David Hall mentioned.  I used the ValueType property when defining the DataGridView.  It now sorts as doubles, no custom event handler code needed

```
dataGridView1.Columns[int index].ValueType = typeof(double);
```

You can also format the column using

```
dataGridView2.Columns[int index].DefaultCellStyle.Format = string format;
```

Comment: Very good suggestion, if it would work. However, for whatever reason, for me this doesn't work. I checked it in the Debugger and the ValueType is indeed given as 'Double', but it doesn't actually sort accordingly.

Comment: @Yellow you may want to check if you are doing `typeof(double)` as opposed to `typeof(Double)`.  One is a class and the other is a variable type. I had similar issues when using the class def Double as well.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric types have a built in CompareTo function, which can be used as the SortResult of the SortCompare event.

```
    private void dataGridView_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Index == 0)
        {
            e.SortResult = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()).CompareTo(int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

This is of course assuming you know the type that was put into the DataGridView to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your database column type should be int or double or float, not varchar or something....
So you have to change your value-type in the database...
You no need to write any code or something it directly sort when you click on the column Header...

Comment: In addition you can change your query to cast the result as int, double or float. You don't need to change the type in database.

Answer (score 0):

It is sorting it by character.  You need to make the column type float so it knows what comparison operator to apply.

(That is you need to make the column type in your dataset float, I believe that will work.)

Comment: yikes!  how are you getting the data into the grid?

Comment: Well... I have a List of a custom struct. That has about 5 string elements contained within it. 

Therefore i can just use a forloop, iterating through the list, and adding them one by one into the datagrid.

Doing it through webscraping, and there is no need to "hold onto" the data once it is in the grid. There is no data manipulation, (except for ordering :P), just using the datagrid for viewing purposes.

Comment: ah I see.  If you define an iterator and properties you can just bind the list to the grid.  It is called a dataobject (for google search).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `datagridview` is sorting by string. Try casting the `string` to `float` when you copy that cell into the `datagrid`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Datagridview Column Header Mouse Click event and the code will be like below:

```
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn clickedColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

            // Check if the clicked column contains float values (adjust the check for your specific column)
            if (clickedColumn.Name == "colScore" || clickedColumn.Name == "colID")
            {
                // Sort using a custom comparer
                dataGridView1.Sort(new FloatColumnComparer(e.ColumnIndex));
            }
        }
    }
```

Later we need to add custom Comparer for sorting. Here we used data type float so that we can use it for sorting integer and float both. The code is below:

```
    private class FloatColumnComparer : IComparer
    {
        private readonly int columnIndex;
        private static bool Ascending = true;

        public FloatColumnComparer(int columnIndex)
        {
            this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
            Ascending ^= true;
        }

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
            DataGridViewRow row2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

            float value1, value2;

            if (float.TryParse(row1.Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString(), out value1) &&
                float.TryParse(row2.Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString(), out value2))
            {
                if (Ascending)
                    return value1.CompareTo(value2);
                else
                    return value2.CompareTo(value1);
            }

            return 0; // If parsing fails or values are not valid floats, consider them equal.
        }
    }
```