# Sorting numerically in a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

This question is closely related to these two ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674670/how-to-sort-string-as-number-in-datagridview-in-winforms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018281/winform-datagridview-numeric-column-sorting)) but I don't think they give a satisfying answer.

I have a `DataGridView` (i.e. a table) with several columns (`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`) of different data types: string, integers and floats. When I click on their respective header, each should be sorted according to their type: string alphabetically and numerical values numerically. I have, simply put, the following code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView grid;
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn stringColumn;
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn doubleColumn;
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn intColumn;


stringColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
doubleColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
intColumn    = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

grid.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        stringColumn,
        doubleColumn,
        intColumn});
```

However, since the default representation is `string`, the numerical values also get sorted alphabetically, for example like this:

```
1, 11, 2, 3, 42, 5
```

Apparently, as an easy way of getting around this, according some threads (e.g. [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/72f8ba5a-0a93-4d2a-b054-a75e919f1b3d/datagridview-sort-number-problem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018281/winform-datagridview-numeric-column-sorting)), the following should work immediately solve the problem:

```
doubleColumn.ValueType = typeof(double);
intColumn.ValueType = typeof(int);
```

However, this solution simply doesn't work in my project: values are still sorted alphabetically. So the question is: why not? In the Debugger, I could see that the value type actually changed to (in the `double` case) `System.Double`, so something is happening at least. But how can I make sure that it actually sorts it accordingly, without writing my own sorter?

Comment: I mean does  your `DataGridView` have `DataSource` assigned to anything?

Comment: Aha, thanks. No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can handle the event `SortCompare` to change how the sorting is done, like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e) {
    //Suppose your interested column has index 1
    if (e.Column.Index == 1){
       e.SortResult = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()).CompareTo(int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()));
       e.Handled = true;//pass by the default sorting
     }
}
```

**NOTE**: The above code **supposes your cell values are convertible to int**.

You said your `DataGridView` doesn't have `DataSource` assigned, that means you `Add` the rows manually, so I think you should use `numeric` values instead of `string` for your cells. That would make the sorting work as you want.

Comment: Changing the SortCompare event is what worked best for me. I have a lot of zeroes in my column and want those to display as empty strings, so I use string as the column type. But when sorting I want them to sort numerically. I just added the following to deal with the cells with empty strings: Convert.ToDecimal(e.CellValue1.ToString() != "" ? e.CellValue1.ToString() : "0") and it works as desired! This answer was a great help!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a `DataTable` then you have to set the `DataType` on the `DataColumn`. Setting `ValueType` on the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` won't help.

You can set it when creating it:

```
table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing column from `string` to `int32` might be helpful:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tableDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++) {
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
    DateTime dtnow = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = dtnow.Subtract(dt);
    tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToInt32( ts.Days.ToString());
}
tableDataGridView.Sort(tableDataGridView.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

For me, it works. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your column ValueType to typeof(int) will work, just remember to make sure you put integers into that column. If the rest of your data contains strings, it can be easy to forget to convert your number from a string to an int.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKeTRPSLxX8 watch this video, it helps a lot

Copying the code from that video:

```
Private Sub dgvDailySales_SortCompare(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles dgvDailySales.SortCompare

Try
            Dim dval1, dval2 As Double

            If Not Double.TryParse(e.CellValue1.ToString, dval1) Then Return
            If Not Double.TryParse(e.CellValue2.ToString, dval2) Then Return

            If dval1 = dval2 Then
                e.SortResult = 0
            ElseIf dval2 > dval1 Then
                e.SortResult = -1
            ElseIf dval1 > dval2 Then
                e.SortResult = 1
            End If
            e.Handled = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33249535)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to order numerically where the column contains a number and to work even when there are alfabetic values.

```
Private Sub grid_SortCompare(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles grid.SortCompare
            If e.Column.Index = grid.Columns("colNrFct").Index Then
                If Not isNumeric(e.CellValue1) And Not isNumeric(e.CellValue2) Then
                    e.SortResult = 0
                ElseIf Not isNumeric(e.CellValue1) And isNumeric(e.CellValue2) Then
                    e.SortResult = -1
                ElseIf isNumeric(e.CellValue1) And Not isNumeric(e.CellValue2) Then
                    e.SortResult = 1
                ElseIf Double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) > Double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()) Then
                    e.SortResult = 1
                ElseIf Double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) < Double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()) Then
                    e.SortResult = -1
                Else
                    e.SortResult = 0
                End If
    
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End Sub
```